# How do you display a webcam feed in GLSL, using Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader, webgl

There are multiple examples on how to display a webcam video using ThreeJS by creating a video texture like so :

```
video = document.getElementById( 'video' );
const texture = new THREE.VideoTexture( video );
texture.colorSpace = THREE.SRGBColorSpace;
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);
const plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
plane.position.set(0.5, 0.5, 0);
```

Where the video is an html element that plays the webcam's feed. But the problem is I can't access the feed and play with it using fragment shaders!

How can I manipulate the webcam's video feed in my shader files? I have the materials for my shader files defined like so :

```
const vsh = await fetch('vertex-shader.glsl');
const fsh = await fetch('fragment-shader.glsl');
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    resolution: { value: new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) },
    time: { value: 0.0 },
  },
  vertexShader: await vsh.text(),
  fragmentShader: await fsh.text()
```

Any ideas or simple examples that show that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your materials shader, add the video feed as a texture like so :

```
const videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video);

//setup material with camera and shaders
const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    resolution: { value: new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) },
    time: { value: 0.0 },
    uTexture: { value: videoTexture }
  },
  vertexShader: await vsh.text(),
  fragmentShader: await fsh.text()
});
```

then animate the video feed like so:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    if (video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA) {
        videoTexture.needsUpdate = true;
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

in your GLSL file, access the camera like so:

```
uniform vec2 resolution;
varying vec2 vUvs;
uniform sampler2D uTexture; 

void main() 
{
vec2 pixelCoords = vUvs /resolution;
vec4 webcamColor = texture2D(uTexture, vUvs);
gl_FragColor = webcamColor;
}
```